# Как взять текст выбранного элемента в listview если используешь свою размметку с двумя полями

Tags: android

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться сделал `ListView` со своей разметкой в 2 колонки, теперь не могу понять как получить при клике текст полей.

Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Код заполнения списка

```
public class FindeActivity extends Activity {
    DataBaseClass sqh;
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb;

    public EditText editText;
    public ListView listView;
    public Button button;
    public String[] stringarray = new String[10];
    public List<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();;
    public ListAdapter adapter;
    public static String query_all="SELECT fio, bithday FROM "
            + DataBaseClass.TABLE_INFO;
    public ArrayList<Contact2> list= new ArrayList<Contact2>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finde);
        sqh = new DataBaseClass(this);
        sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_finde);
        Cursor cursor = sqdb.rawQuery(query_all, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                 list.add(new Contact2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.FIO)),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.Bithday))));
                }
        }
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_finde);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_clients);
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.my_listview, new String[] { Contact2.NAME, Contact2.ID }, new int[] {R.id.tvName, R.id.tvID});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Код адаптера

```
public class Contact2 extends HashMap<String, String> {
    public static String NAME="name", ID ="id";

    public Contact2(String name, String id){
        super();
        super.put(NAME, name);
        super.put(ID, id);
    }
}
```

Нужен код обработчика

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,
                    long id) {}
});
```

Comment: Получить элемент списка через getItem

Answer (score 2):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
                       TextView tv1 = (TextView)itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                       TextView tv2 = (TextView)itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
                       String name = tv1.getText().toString();
                       String id = tv2.getText().toString();
}
});
```